# Select cell based on other values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script where I am trying to send emails, and I have *almost* everything figured out. The last piece is actually selecting the email string from a list of rules.

I want to get the emails (col C) if curSheet.getSheetName() = value in colA **AND** newVal = value in colB. I am having trouble combining if statements & for loops.

Here is a link to a sample Notification Rules sheet:
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cn9R3f85xF_QnOU_BNIvpqRq8FUvRGFaCUnTH3jyCTs/edit#gid=0]

```
function emailUpdate(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var curSheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

var notifSheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"]

var newVal = e.value
var row = e.range.rowStart
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
var hosp = curSheet.getRange(row,4).getValue()

var sheetID = curSheet.getSheetId()
var sheetURL = "linktodoc"+sheetID

var rules = ss.getSheetByName('Notification Rules')
var data = rules.getDataRange().getValues()

//Build Email
var subject = subjecttext
    var intro = introtext
    var closer = closingtext

  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && notifSheets.indexOf(curSheet.getSheetName()) != -1 && newVal !== undefined) {
    console.log("It worked")
    curSheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(curDate) //inserts edit date

    var email = //some for / if statement to get colC if colA&colB match curSheet & newVal  

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,'', {htmlBody: intro+closer})
    
  } else {
    console.log("It didn't work")
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the function executed?

Comment: It is an on onEdit trigger! First it checks some values (curSheet, edited col, etc). Everything works as is - I just haven't figured out how to define the correct email cell

Comment: When I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet, only a sheet of "Notifaction Rules" is existing. In this case, `notifSheets.indexOf(curSheet.getSheetName()) != -1` is always `false`, because of `var notifSheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"]`. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do here. So I cannot propose the modified script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. At least, I think that your current issue is due to the above.